# clone via http a git repo linked to /var/www

Tags: git, apache, git-clone

I have a webserver apache2 that can list files in the /var/www directory of my computer.
I have two bare repos `repo1.git` and `repo2.git`. The first is located in `/var/www/git/repo1.git`, while the second is a symbolic link:

```
/var/www/git/repo2.git -> /other/folder/repo2.git
```

Now, if I go with the web browser to `http://myserver.com/git/repo1.git`, I can see the internal files of the bare repo and if I go to `myserver.com/repo1.git` I can see similar files (I can go also in the subdirectories).

I can clone `repo1.git` via `git clone http://myserver.com/git/repo1.git` without issues.

The problem is when I try to clone `repo2.git`:

```
fatal: repository 'http://myserver.com/git/repo2.git' not found
```

**Other info:**

I have enabled the hook post-update in both the repos.
My apache.conf includes the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/git>
    Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Do you have any idea of what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot expose your file systems over http and expect git to work.

Git internally has an API that every git client understands, this helps Git track meta information besides the file system.

Have a [read here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) (particularly the HTTP section) and you will know the sequence of steps that git follows for every operations (clone, push etc.)

If you need to host your own git server over http, I'd suggest something like [git-webby](https://code.google.com/p/git-webby/) or [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) or [Gitlab](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq).

If your interest is academic, [this blog](http://stefan.saasen.me/articles/git-clone-in-haskell-from-the-bottom-up/) takes you through implementing git clone from scratch using Haskell.